# C# SharePoint 2010 Permission denied on zip creation

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have a sharePoint 2010 application creating excel and pdf files. I created a routine to zip all the created folders / files but I got "Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permission.FileIO.Permission, mscorlib, ...'" error. 
Below is my codes. I have tried that on a webform project and it works fine.
I used ionic.zip library

```
   public void GetZipOfFile(string zipname, string DirectoryToZip)
   {
  try
    {
       zipname += ".zip";
       HttpResponse oResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;
       oResponse.Clear();
       oResponse.Charset = "";
       using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
       {
         System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryToZip);
         zip.Comment = String.Format("This zip archive was created For Access Bank InfoPool");
         zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
         zip.AddDirectory(DirectoryToZip);
         zip.Save(oResponse.OutputStream);
         zip.Dispose();
       }
       oResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
       oResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + zipname + "\"");
        oResponse.End();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     lblMessage.Visible = true;
     lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
  }   
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve! It was an issue with trust level. I was editing a wrong config file (I was not the initial developer, I joined to complete it).

Thanks everyone.